# make long css path short in selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

The CSS selector I'm using is

```
#menu-container > div.navbar-collapse.collapse.bs-navbar-collapse > ul:nth-child(1) > li.dropdown.open > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a > span.menu-label
```

Is there a way to make it shorter?

HTML

```
<div id="menu-container" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand">SmartStudio</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse bs-navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">File</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <span class="pull-left"></span>
                            <span class="menu-label">Save</span>
                            <span class="pull-right">⌘ S</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <span class="pull-left"></span>
                            <span class="menu-label">Fonts</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"><span></span></li>
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <span class="pull-left"></span>
                            <span class="menu-label">Publish</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Edit</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <span class="pull-left"></span>
                            <span class="menu-label">Undo</span>
                            <span class="pull-right">⌘ Z</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <span class="pull-left"></span>
                            <span class="menu-label">Redo</span>
                            <span class="pull-right">⇧ ⌘ Z</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"><span></span></li>
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <span class="pull-left"></span>
                            <span class="menu-label">Cut</span>
                            <span class="pull-right">⌘ X</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <span class="pull-left"></span>
                            <span class="menu-label">Copy</span>
                            <span class="pull-right">⌘ C</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <span class="pull-left"></span>
                            <span class="menu-label">Paste</span>
                            <span class="pull-right">⌘ V</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <span class="pull-left"></span> its too long to use in code. Is there a way to make it shorter in selenium web driver?
                            <span class="menu-label">Paste in Place</span>
                            <span class="pull-right">⇧ ⌘ V</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"><span></span></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a>
                            <span class="pull-left"></span>
                            <span class="menu-label">Arrange</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a>
                                    <span class="pull-left"></span>
                                    <span class="menu-label">Bring to Front</span>
                                    <span class="pull-right">⇧ ⌘ ↑</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a>
                                    <span class="pull-left"></span>
                                    <span class="menu-label">Bring Forward</span>
                                    <span class="pull-right">⌘ ↑</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a>
                                    <span class="pull-left"></span>
                                    <span class="menu-label">Send Backward</span>
                                    <span class="pull-right">⌘ ↓</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a>
                                    <span class="pull-left"></span>
                                    <span class="menu-label">Send to Back</span>
                                    <span class="pull-right">⇧ ⌘ ↓</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">View</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <span class="pull-left"></span>
                            <span class="menu-label">Hide Panels</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <span class="pull-left"></span>
                            <span class="menu-label">Hide Off Page Dimming</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Panel</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <span class="pull-left icon icon-check"></span>
                            <span class="menu-label">Project</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <span class="pull-left icon icon-check"></span>
                            <span class="menu-label">Properties</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <span class="pull-left icon icon-check"></span>
                            <span class="menu-label">Design</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown open"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Help</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <span class="pull-left"></span>
                            <span class="menu-label">Support Resources</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <span class="pull-left"></span>
                            <span class="menu-label">Rate Us</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>
                            <span class="pull-left"></span>
                            <span class="menu-label">Suggest a Feature</span>
                        </a>
```

Comment: You'll have to post the relevant HTML if you want us to provide a shorter selector. Why is your selector "too long"? It is what it is...

Comment: @JeffC, i think now u can give me better suggestion

Comment: When you post HTML please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ to properly format it. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Also please narrow the HTML down to only the relevant parts. Which element are you trying to click? This looks like a job for XPath.

Comment: at the end of my code, i want the css path of 
    <span class="menu-label">Support Resources</span>
     and i need css path because i also run it in safari browser where xpath makes problem

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to figure out for sure without seeing the HTML you're referring to. However, it looks like you may be able to get away with this:

`#menu-container span.menu-label`

It looks like you're acquainted with the `>` operator, which selects a direct child of an element. The  operator (a space) selects any descendant of an element.

This only works if there are no other `span`s with a class of `menu-label` inside of the element with the ID of `menu-container`. I'm assuming this is the case.

If you want a more certain answer, you'll need to provide a complete HTML file.

EDIT: Okay, now that you've provided your HTML, it's very clear what the problem is: your HTML is using styling classes, but no descriptive classes. You have two choices: adding more specific classes to your HTML elements, or just dealing with your very long selector. There are no other options.

Of course, if you choose the second option, you should store that CSS selector in a variable to give it a useful name, make it reusable, and make it easy to change when needed.

Comment: actually the code is big and if i use ur code it finds 5 match.
here menu-container is a id and span.menu-label exist in other <li>.can u please give me some more specific suggestion?

Comment: Okay. This can go one of three ways. 1) Your HTML is a problematic first draft and needs a simpler structure and more classes. 2) Your Selenium test is doing something over-specific. Integration tests should cover more general use cases. 3) Your selector is fine as you wrote it, and you'll just have to handle its length.

There's no "magic CSS selector" that means all the things you posted in your question.

Comment: please give me better suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got several options... I'll list a couple that you can try and see if they work for you.

The super simplest way is to use the link text of the menu and then the submenu items. It may or may not work... one issue may be the uniqueness of the "Help" link on the page, there may be more than one. It looks like you will have to click the Help menu to expose the submenu that contains the "Support Resources" link.

```
String menuName = "Help";
String submenuName = "Support Resources";
driver.findElement(By.linkText(menuName)).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText(submenuName)).click();
```

If that doesn't work, this should... or at least point you in the right direction. You will need to loop through the menus looking for the correct link text, click on it exposing the submenu, loop through the submenus looking for the correct link text, and then click on it.

```
String menuName = "Help";
String submenuName = "Support Resources";
List<WebElement> menus = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#menu-container > div > ul.nav.navbar-nav > li.dropdown"));
// List<WebElement> menus = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#menu-container li.dropdown")); // possible shorter alternative
for (WebElement menu : menus)
{
    if (menu.getText().equals(menuName))
    {
        menu.click();
        List<WebElement> submenus = menu.findElements(By.cssSelector("span.menu-label"));
        for (WebElement submenu : submenus)
        {
            if (submenu.getText().equals(submenuName))
            {
                submenu.click();
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```